# Oracle multi dimensional query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in an Oracle database which has a large number of dates. Referred to as LOG_DATE.
This is the query to produce the output below:

```
SELECT *
FROM ITAR.LOG_ITEM 
WHERE ACTION='APPROVE' 

LOG_ITEM LOG_DATE              ACTION  REQUEST
1        2014-10-15 13:51:24.0 APPROVE POSTPONE
2        2014-11-18 14:54:47.0 APPROVE CLOSE
3        2014-11-18 15:55:47.0 APPROVE POSTPONE
4        2014-11-19 14:52:47.0 APPROVE CLOSE
5        2014-09-17 14:22:37.0 APPROVE POSTPONE
```

I would like to produce a multidimensional output based on a single query.
The output should like something like this:

```
           THIS_MONTH THIS_QUARTER THIS_YEAR
POSTPONE            1            2         3
CLOSE               2            2         2
```

Any ideas of how I can do this with Oracle-SQL alone?

It would be good if it could be "dynamic" i.e. so that months, quarters and year are not hard-coded into the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dynamic solution, you'll need to create a quarter lookup table and associate each quarter with a month.  Then you can join on that table or use a correlated subquery.

Here's the basic idea of what you want though which uses `group by`, and `count` with `case`:

```
select request, 
  count(case when trunc(log_date,'mm') = trunc(sysdate,'mm') then 1 end) this_month,
  count(case when extract(month from log_date) in (10,11,12) then 1 end) this_quarter,
  count(1) this_year
from log_item
where log_date >= to_date('1/1/2014','mm/dd/yyyy')
group by request
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ce35/2)

---

**EDIT**: given @OllieJones comment below, this actually will work for you without needing a quarters lookup table:

```
select request, 
  count(case when trunc(log_date,'mm') = trunc(sysdate,'mm') then 1 end) this_month,
  count(case when trunc(log_date,'Q') = trunc(sysdate,'Q') then 1 end) this_quarter,
  count(1) this_year
from log_item
where log_date >= trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')
group by request
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ce35/9)

Comment: `TRUNC(log_date,'Q')` will actually produce calendar quarter truncation. So, you may not need the `(10,11,12)` stuff.